# How to put line between nodes in kendo RTL treeview?

Tags: angularjs, css, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I working by Kendo UI RTL TreeView .I Use Angular js tree view and right to left like this [Kendo TreeView RTL](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/right-to-left-support).
Now,I want put line between nodes,I do it but lines dosn't work me correctly.
How can I do it ?

```css
<style>
   /*-------------------line between nodes-----------------*/

            body {
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      .k-treeview .k-top,
      .k-treeview .k-mid,
      .k-treeview .k-bot {
        background-image: url('http://aspnet-skins.telerikstatic.com/mvc/2012.2.607/Default/treeview-nodes.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-right: -16px;
        padding-right: 16px;
      }

      .k-treeview .k-item { background-image: url('http://aspnet-skins.telerikstatic.com/mvc/2012.2.607/Default/treeview-line.png'); }
      .k-treeview .k-last { background-image: none; }


      .k-treeview .k-top { background-position: -91px 0; 
             
             background-position-x: right; }
      .k-treeview .k-bot {  background-position: -47px -44px;
             
             background-position-x: right; }
      .k-treeview .k-mid {  background-position: -69px -22px;
            
             background-position-x: right;}
      .k-treeview .k-last .k-top { background-position: -25px -66px; 
            
             background-position-x: right;}
      .k-treeview .k-group .k-last .k-bot { background-position: -69px -22px; 
            
             background-position-x: right;}

      .k-treeview .k-item {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }

      .k-treeview .k-first {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 16px;
      }

         /*------------------end of line between nodes-----------*/
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should flip horizontal your images and change the background positions.
you can see a sample in this page https://github.com/vira1368/KendoUI_TreeView_RTL